# A Chi-Squared fit of a general quadratic polynomial is done to ten data points. What is the number of degrees of freedom of this fit?

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

I think the correct answer is $7$ because the general quadratic is $$y_i=ax_i^2 + bx_i + c$$

Using the formula $$\color{red}{\fbox{Number of degrees of freedom = Number of data points - Number of Parameters}}$$

The $3$ parameters are $y_i,x_i^2,x_i$

So $10-3=7$ degrees of freedom.

The correct answer is indeed $7$; But is this because $x_i^2$ 'counts' as $2$ parameters as it's squared (adding the other $x_i$ to make $3$)?

I am somewhat new to this idea of degrees of freedom; so I'm not really sure which method is valid, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several comments:

- $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the parameters you are trying to estimate.
- $\{y_i, x_i, x_i^2\}$ is your data.
- Your estimators $\hat{a}$, $\hat{b}$, and $\hat{c}$ are functions of your data.
- Your data has 10 degrees of freedom because it has 10 different observations.
- Your model has 3 degrees of freedom because you are estimating three separate values. (Some people don't count the constant $c$ and call it 2 degrees of freedom.)
- Your residuals have 10 - 3 = 7 degrees of freedom.
- The residual vector is a 10 dimensional vector (because there are 10 residuals) but the vector lives in a 7 dimensional subspace (because it only has 7 degrees of freedom)!

Comment: Very nicely explained, (+1) just one more question; What is a constraint in this context? Are the $\{y_i, x_i, x_i^2\}$ constraints, probability theory is not my strong point. I have seen another equation that states: $\color{blue}{\fbox{Number of degrees of freedom = Number of data points - Number of Constraints}}$? If this is true then it means that a Constraint is simply a synonym for a Parameter, is this correct?

Comment: @BLAZE I'd have to see the context to be able to say anything. It doesn't strike me as completely standard usage/terminology? but maybe in context, I'd get it.

Comment: I have found some context for the word 'constraint' please see this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583098/lost-in-terminology-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-words-constraint-and-paramete). You have been of great help in answering this question, so thought you might like to try the next one.

Answer (score 4):

The parameters are $a,b,c$ and not $y_i, x_i, x_i^2$ as you pointed out.

Comment: Are you sure about this as the $a,b,c$ are just constants say $4x^2 + 3x -2$? It is the $y_i, x_i, x_i^2$ that are varying with each $i$.

Comment: $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the parameters you are trying to estimate. ${y_i, x_i, x_i^2}$ is your data.  Your estimators $\hat{a}$, $\hat{b}$, and $\hat{c}$ are functions of your data. Your data has 10 degrees of freedom because it has 10 observations. Your model has 3 degrees of freedom because you are estimating three separate values (some people don't count the constant $c$ and call it 2 degrees of freedom). Your residuals have 10 - 3 = 7 degrees of freedom. There are 10 residuals (i.e. the residual vector has 10 dimensions) but they live in a 7 dimensional subspace!

Comment: @right Thanks for your answer, I appreciate that (+1) :)